# Date function query

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

Hi I was wondering if there is a date function I can use to retain the Month and Year of a date field that has the following value `12/03/2015`. I just want the Month and Year extracted but in a date type and not a string.

I have used `datepart`, but it can only take one part at a time and concatenating both month and year seems to make it into a string that SSRS can't interpret. I am hoping to do all the hardwork on the database then use SSRS to covert to `MM/YYYY` which I seem to have problems with if the report is ran more than 12 months.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You can't have a DATE without the day. As a workaround you might set the day to the 1st of month by subtracting the *day of the month - 1*

Answer (score 0):

As [dnoeth] says, you can not have a date without a day.

But you can add a column to your query like this:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,[date_column]) AS NVARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(DATEPART(YEAR,[date_column]) As NVARCHAR(4)) AS MonthYear
```

This will create the value you want.

Then in SSRS in case you need to sort, you can configure it to sort on your date_column that is of the type DATETIME

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer **"NO"**

> Sql does't have a pre-defined function to do this, It's impossible to
>   do this without concatenating both month and year but the return type will in string format.

*This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186724.aspx) will help you to understand Date and Time Data Types and Functions*

> Below image will help you to understand different types of data type
>   formats exists in sql.

[image: Date and Time Data Types]